# Is there a way to get reporting on Google Voice usage?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is there a way I can leverage the Google APIs to get a report on Google Voice usage in my domain? We just turned it on and wanted to see if any of our users were using the service.

Answer (score 0):

Google Voice is not a core service within Google Apps and does not fall under [Google's SLA](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/terms/sla.html). There are also no official APIs that allow access to Google Voice data. There is however at least one [unofficial Python library](https://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/) to interact with Google Voice programatically.

Comment: Thanks. FYI, there are APIs that exist for services that are not considered CORE services, so I'm not sure what you were pointing out there.

Comment: simply that it's not covered or supported from a "Google Apps domain" perspective. Your question was if there was a way to gather "usage in my domain" but since it's not a core offering, there are no admin-level API calls.